# Facebook Application: How can I deny direct access on my server?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

Is there a way to deny direct access to the application server for a facebook application?

Facebook loads the application via an iFrame src=http://app-domain/, but you can clearly view the page source and find out that domain and copy paste the URL into a browser and view the application directly.

There is this signed_request and oauth_token in the API, I was wondering how to use that or if I can use that to limit direct access to the application.

So if a user inputs in the browser your application's URL he gets redirected to Facebook.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I found a way that also works with form submission.

```
// Signed request
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if(!$signed_request) header("Location: " . $settings['appBaseUrl']);
```

This redirects the browser while accessing the application directly and not through facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that also works with form submission. (Works for me, it might not work for you. Test it first.)

```
// Signed request
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if(!$signed_request) header("Location: " . $settings['appBaseUrl']);
```

This redirects the browser while accessing the application directly and not through facebook.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work if javascript is disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;

    if(!isInIFrame){
                window.location = 'link-of-application-page';
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some Javascript to detect whether you're in Facebook's frame and if you're not, redirect to it.

Comment: What if the user disables javascript?